# Получить список сотрудников из выбранного отдела, а также его дочерних отделов

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

Не получается придумать такое Linq выражение, результатом которого являются все сотрудники отдела и сотрудники его дочерних отделов(их может быть бесконечно).
Так вот существует таблица Department:

```cs
    public sealed partial class Department
    {
        public int Id { get => id; set => this.id = value; }

        public string NameDepartment { get => this.nameDepartment; set => this.nameDepartment = value; }

        public int ParentId { get => this.parentId; set => this.parentId = value; }
```

А также таблица Worker:

```cs
    public partial class Worker
    {
        public int Id { get => this.id; set => this.id = value; }

        public string FirstName { get => this.firstName; set => this.firstName = value; }

        public string LastName { get => this.lastName; set => this.lastName = value; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get => this.dateOfBirth; set => this.dateOfBirth = value; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get => this.phoneNumber; set => this.phoneNumber = value; }

        public int DepartmentId { get => this.departmentId; set => this.departmentId = value; }
```

[image: Скрин]

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с этим и поможет. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: У вас в дереве уже все департаменты есть, значит за департаментами не надо лазать в БД, их все можно собрать и так. Ну и потом собирайте все айдишки нужных департаментов и делавйте запрос `var workers = myDbContext.Workers.Where(w=>mydepatramentIds.Contains(w.DepartmentId));` и все дела

Comment: @tym32167 То есть я получаю допустим List<int> айдишников дочерних отделов  и подставляю его вместо mydepartmentIds в вашем примере?

Comment: да, просто `List<int>` айдишников всех нужных вам отделов.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо большое. Это мне помогло, осталось только оптимизировать) Можете оформить ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в дереве уже все департаменты есть, значит за департаментами не надо лазать в БД, их все можно собрать и так. Ну и потом собирайте все айдишки нужных департаментов и делавйте запрос

```
var workers = myDbContext.Workers.Where(w=>mydepatramentIds.Contains(w.DepartmentId));
```

и все дела.